# RuntimeError: `RunConfig` instance is expected to be used by the `Estimator` inside the `Experiment`

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to run this tutorial experiment:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction#local-train-single

Running locally, in `virtualenv`, Python v2.7, TensorFlow v1.2

When executing this command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --package-path trainer/ \
    -- \
    --train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
    --eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
    --train-steps 1000 \
    --job-dir $MODEL_DIR \
    --eval-steps 100
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: `RunConfig` instance is expected to be used by the `Estimator` inside the `Experiment`. 

expected 
_cluster_spec={}, 
_environment=u'cloud', 
_evaluation_master='', 
_is_chief=True, 
_master='', 
_model_dir='output', 
_num_ps_replicas=0, 
_num_worker_replicas=0, 
_task_id=0, 
_task_type=None, 
_tf_config=<tensorflow.core.protobuf.config_pb2.ConfigProto object at 0x111833938>, 

but got 
_cluster_spec={}, 
_environment=u'cloud', 
_evaluation_master='', 
_is_chief=True, 
_master='', 
_model_dir='output', 
_num_ps_replicas=0, 
_num_worker_replicas=0, 
_task_id=0, 
_task_type=None, 
_tf_config=<tensorflow.core.protobuf.config_pb2.ConfigProto object at 0x111833c80>
```

So, it appears it is not finding the `_tf_config` at the right address.  Have not been able to find documentation on how to set that up.  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Appears to have something to do with my `virtualenv` setup.  Works fine when I install tensorflow natively.